# Is it possible to supress MessageBoxes programmatically?

Tags: windows-services, hide, messagebox

Say I have an executable (MB.exe) that simply displays a MessageBox when run.

Is is possible to call this executable from another program or using a command in the command-line and make it so that MB.exe still runs but simply doesn't display the MessageBox? (kind of like the way Windows services don't display messageBoxes except if you check the "Allow service to interact with desktop" option in the Properties menu in services.msc)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the program attempts to display a message box. Hang unresponsively until terminated, or do skip the messagebox or log the messagebox content somewhere?

Comment: There are ways to completely hide a Windows application's UI and message boxes, but if the message box or any dialog is shown, the hidden application will be stuck at that point. Unless you deal with that programmatically. Depending on the case it might be easier to just reverse engineer the original program, so please add more details.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN "do skip the messagebox"

Comment: @Renan Windows services seem to have done this somehow. If you have a MessageBox in a service, it won't display. It'll just skip it. There has to be some way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried launching the application from a service so that is is already running in a context that doesn't allow interaction with the UI?

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I'd like to achieve this from a desktop application or a script...

Comment: Hiding the UI is one thing, automatically dismissing the message box is another. Are you saying you want to do both?

Comment: @CoreTech I want to hide it but I don't want it to block the application. If, by dismiss you mean the equivalent of pressing the escape key or the window's X button when it displays, then indeed dismissing it would be an acceptable solution. And to answer your question, no, not necessarily both. Either of the two suffice.

Answer (score 0):

For automatically dismissing popups and other windows, we have had success with [Buzof](http://www.basta.com/Buzof) (for applications that run on the desktop) and [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) (which we use to construct automation scripts to support our Windows Services products).